# Backbone.js: this.model is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I've spent the past two weeks trying to learn Backbone.js and then also modularizing the app with Require.js. But seems there are something that I'm not getting in the whole process of initialization and fetching.

I have two routes, one shows an entire collection while the other shows just an individual model. And I want to be able to start the app with any of both routes.

If I start loading the collections url and later on a single model url, everything works as expected. If I start the app with the url route to a single model I got the error: `TypeError: this.model is undefined this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));`on the view.

If I set defaults for the model, it renders the view but doesn't fetch it with the real data. I've tried also to handle the success event in the fetch function of the model without any luck.

**router.js**

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','models/offer','collections/offers','views/header','views/event','views/offer/list', 
], function($, _, Backbone, OfferModel, OffersCollection, HeaderView, EventView, OfferListView){

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({    

routes: {
    'event/:id' : 'showEvent',
  '*path': 'showOffers'
},

initialize : function() {       
    this.offersCollection = new OffersCollection();
    this.offersCollection.fetch();
    var headerView = new HeaderView();
    $('#header').html(headerView.render().el);          
},

showEvent : function(id) {
    if (this.offersCollection) {
        this.offerModel = this.offersCollection.get(id);
    } else {
        this.offerModel = new OfferModel({id: id});
        this.offerModel.fetch();
    }       
    var eventView = new EventView({model: this.offerModel});    
    $('#main').html(eventView.render().el);     
},

showOffers : function(path) {
    if (path === 'betting' || path === 'score') {
        var offerListView = new OfferListView({collection: this.offersCollection, mainTemplate: path});  
      $('#main').html(offerListView.render().el) ;       
    }       
},    
});

var initialize = function(){    
  window.router = new AppRouter;
  Backbone.history.start();
};

return {
  initialize: initialize
};
});
```

**views/event.js**

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','text!templates/event/main.html',
], function($, _, Backbone, eventMainTemplate){

var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initalize : function(options) {
        this.model = options.model; 
        this.model.on("change", this.render);       
    },

    render : function() {
        var tmpl = _.template(eventMainTemplate);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

return EventView;   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and fetching the OffersCollection in `initialize` method of the router, so the `else` block in `showEvent` will never be hit since `this.offersCollection` is always truthy.

After the comments, I think you need to do this:

```
showEvent : function(id) {
    var that = this;
    var show = function(){
       var eventView = new EventView({model: that.offerModel});    
       $('#main').html(eventView.render().el); 
    };
    // offersCollection is always defined, so check if it has the model
    if (this.offersCollection && this.offersCollection.get(id)) {
        this.offerModel = this.offersCollection.get(id);
        show();
    } else {
        this.offerModel = new OfferModel({id: id});
        this.offerModel.fetch().done(function(){
           // model is fetched, show now to avoid your render problems.
           show();
        });
        // alternatively, set the defaults in the model,
        // so you don't need to wait for the fetch to complete.
    }       

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this before but when it renders the view sees that the model is not fetched yet so I get ´ReferenceError: attribute is not defined`for every attribute except the `id`.

Comment: You get that in EventView's `render`?  Then you need to wait for the fetch to complete before first render, or make your render method handle an unfetched model.

Comment: Underscore throws the error so I understand it's in the render of the template.

Comment: I've tried again to handle the success event in the fetch function and now it works, so I don't now what I was doing wrong before...

Comment: Anyway, how would you handle the unfetched model? I think it is the option that makes more sense.

Comment: I think you still do need to create/fetch the collection in the route handler instead of initialize.  But then to fix the template, either add defaults to the model, or maybe have some conditional code in the template to avoid errors, but that is hard to say without seeing the template code.

Comment: I create/fetch the collection on initialize to avoid calling the api every time I load the routes betting or score, as they use the same collection but with different templates.

Comment: Then you must do something like `if (this.offersCollection && this.offersCollection.get(id))` or your `else` will never be hit.

Comment: Using your second edit of the answer I'm still getting the same `this.model is undefined` as it's trying to get the model from the collection that seems hasn't been yet fetched on initialize(). If I add the checking it goes trough the else fetching from the api for the single model, but throwing the same error.

Comment: I think it may be related to the use of this. I have to leave the office now but I'll check it later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is really weird, but if I create a local variable `var offerModel` instead of using `this.offerModel` it's working perfectly, but I don't have any idea of why it behaves like that.

Comment: Probably because `this` is not right in some callback function.

Comment: Edited my answer with one place `this` was wrong.  You can put a breakpoint in Chrome dev tools each place you are using `this.offerModel` and see if it is right or wrong.